# Rodando um projeto laravel do git na minha maquina

Tags: laravel, git

Eu coloquei um projeto laravel da minha maquina no git com o git ignore padrão.

Depois pra usar em outro pc eu baixei do git pela linha de comando e tentei instalar o composer:

```
composer install
```

Mas ele não instalar o .env e outras coisas senão me engano

Daí eu criei um projeto novo com o mesmo nome pelo CLI, depois copiei o projeto que baixei do git e colei por cima do projeto novo e funcionou.

Queria saber se tem um jeito com menos gambiarra pra fazer isso funcionar, ou seja sem precisar criar um projeto novo, baixar outro do git e copiar e colar um no outro

Comment: Unica coisa que você precisa é o arquivo .env, que você pode copiar do .env.example. Que outras coisas você precisa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No .gitignore você escolhe qual arquivo ou pasta, que não vai ser enviado, ao realizar o commit esse arquivo não é adicionado e ao realizar o push esse arquivo ou pasta não é enviado, se você você quer que o .env seja enviado remova do .gitignore, agora isso não é aconselhado. A mesma situação se a aplica ao "/vendor", não há necessidade de você mandar todos esses arquivos se você pode realizar um composer install depois de clonar o projeto.

Comment: Quando eu rodo o composer install ele não adiciona o .env no projeto local

Comment: Composer é uma ferramenta para gerenciamento de dependências para o PHP, quando você executa o comando "composer install", ele irá instalar as dependências. Ele não irá acrescentar o .env. Quando você baixa a estrutura do Laravel, por exemplo a versão 5.5, vem um arquivo chamado .env.example, mas é só quando você baixa a estrutura. se você quer que o .env venha sempre ao clonar seu projeto, remova-o do .gitignore. Agora não suba com nenhum dado de produção, é muito perigoso.

Comment: @lipesmile Conseguiu entender a finalidade do composer ? Fez o teste removendo-o o .env do .gitignore ?